# How navigate to single screen inside tab navigation. react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

So this is the case. I have let's say login screen which is tab based, one tab is login and other one is register. I also have "Forgot password" button. So when I press forgot password button I want to go to a single screen which does not contain tab navigation and has that "back" button in it's header.

This is my Navigator if this is helps in any way:

```js
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
});

LoginStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Login',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={"login"}
    />
  ),
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "black",
  }
};

const RegisterStack = createStackNavigator({
  Register: RegisterScreen,
});

RegisterStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Register',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={"account-plus"}
    />
  ),
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "black",
  }
};


export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  LoginStack,
  RegisterStack,
});
```

If you need any more info, please comment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly exporting createBottomTabNavigator, you create tabs then follow as below

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  LoginStack,
  RegisterStack,
});
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Tabs,
ForgotPassword: {
screen: ForgotPassword,
}
}) //fixed brackets
export AppNavigator
```